# UIStackView that responds gestures like UITableView

Tags: swift, uitableview, uigesturerecognizer, uistackview

Question is simple, it is about adding gestures to horizontal `stackView` that has gestures like tableview. Think of horizontal `tableView` but also has certain stop points.(Avoiding view to stop any point.) To be more clear, A horizontal working `tableView` with its gesture features (bouncing, sliding, etc) and has `tableViewCell`'s that has same size of the `UIWindow`. Finally let's after sliding, it can not stop at a point that reveal's 2 `cell`'s at the same time. I hope it's clear.

Purpose of this making a background to tell people about the app in `Login` page. I thought `stackView` would be best for that job but if you have better way, please inform me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for UIPageViewController instead of using a stackView. A great tutorial can be found here: https://spin.atomicobject.com/2015/12/23/swift-uipageviewcontroller-tutorial/

Im not sure what you mean with "A horizontal working tableView" but if you are looking for a PageViewController that can scroll up and down check this out: https://github.com/stefanceriu/SCPageViewController You can do a lot more with this.

Comment: You, sir, are the real MVP.